# C creating node to contain name and age from user input

Tags: c, linked-list

i am trying to create a linked list of a strings and integer as presented here name & age. put so far it is not working well !
if some one can explain where is my mistakes and how to fix them !!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
    char* name;
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void)
{
    // Creating a Node to store the data.
     struct node* Node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    //Ask the user to enter a Name.
     printf("Enter name: ");

     //scanning the input and store it into the Node name part.
     scanf("%s\n", Node-> name);

     //ask the user to enter age.
     printf("Enter age:");

     //scanning the input and store it into the Node age part.
     scanf("%d\n", &Node-> value);


     printf(" Name:%s , Age:%d\n %p\n  ",Node -> name ,Node -> value, &Node);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you haven't create space for the `name`.
2. don't use `\n` on `scanf`.
3. i don't know why you printing the pointer but you don't need to use `&Node` because it's already a pointer.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
    char* name;
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void)
{
    // Creating a Node to store the data.
    struct node* Node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    //Ask the user to enter a Name.
    printf("Enter name: ");

    Node->name = malloc(sizeof (char) * 100); // max 100 chars
    //scanning the input and store it into the Node name part.
    scanf("%s", Node-> name);

    //ask the user to enter age.
    printf("Enter age: ");

    //scanning the input and store it into the Node age part.
    scanf("%d", &Node-> value);

    printf(" Name:%s , Age:%d\n %p\n",Node -> name ,Node -> value, Node);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok that works , but i need to understand why the part" char* name " doesn't count as a space holder  for 4 bytes !!?

and can i allocate this space "100 char " in the node structure declaration ?

Comment: about the third point "i don't know why you printing the pointer but you don't need to use &Node because it's already a pointer."

 i wanted to see the address of the node , just to learn how to print it ...

but now i am using both Node and &Node to see the address but i find two different addresses , like :

 0x17462a0
 0x7ffd38513ae8

why is that !!, shouldn't it be the same !?

Comment: @NIO sorry for the late reply, I think you doesn't understand what is a pointer. a pointer is a number, a address of memory (RAM). when we need memory for something we use `malloc` and it gives us a address. so `char* name` is a address/pointer, you need to request memory for it. every time you use a pointer, something like `<data type> *`, you will have to manually request enough memory.

Comment: pointers are use to contain addresses. we use `node* Node` to store a address. you create new address when you use `mallloc` and `node* Node` contains that, when you use `&Node` you requests the address of the container, not the address of value.

Comment: regarding pointer address, 
your replay means that, i create a container with " node* Node" that will hold the value allocated in another space in memory with " malloc" , am i getting this right ?

cuz this will explain so much